# Getting SQL data for a report with Time Difference count in VB ASP.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, charts, report

I have been struggling to get the report to show correctly. What I'm trying to achieve is that I have projects with estimated working hours. Employees log their Timesheet entries, the (start\end) date and time gets saved into an SQL table for this particular project and employee, so I want to report the estimated preset hours of the project against the time really spent by employees, here is the scenario of what I'm doing with code:

The Tables I have:

1-Projects Table---> ProjectID,Estimate Project Estimate Duration(in Hours)
2-ProjectResources Table--->ProjectID, ResourceID
3-Timesheet Entries Table--->Timesheetentry ID, ProjectID, UserID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime

What I have created is as follows:

1-I populate a drop down list with project Names as text and project IDs as value

### 2-On the list selectedIndexChanged event I query to get all resources of Project as follows:

Dim TimesheetsTotalTime As Decimal = 0
Dim query As String = "SELECT resourceid FROM projectresources where projectID='" & ProjectID & "'"
Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query)

For x As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim resourceID As Integer
                resourceID = dt.Rows(x).Item(0)
                totalTimesheetTime = totalTimesheetTime + GetTotalTimesheetsPerUser(ProjectID, resourceID)

### Next

Private Shared Function GetTotalTimesheetsPerUser(ProjectID As Integer, ResourceID As Integer) As Decimal
        Dim TimesheetsTotalTime As Decimal = 0

```
    Dim query As String = "SELECT timesheetid FROM timesheet where projectID='" & ProjectID & "' and userid='" & ResourceID & "'"

    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query)

    For x As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim TimesheetID As Integer
        TimesheetID = dt.Rows(x).Item(0).ToString

        TimesheetsTotalTime = TimesheetsTotalTime + GetTimeDifferenceForTask(TimesheetID)

    Next
    Return TimesheetsTotalTime
```

### End Function

Private Shared Function GetTimeDifferenceForTask(timeSheetID As Integer) As Decimal
        Dim CountedHours As Decimal

```
    Dim query As String = "SELECT StartTime, EndTime FROM Timesheet where TimesheetID='" & timeSheetID & "'"
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim startTime As DateTime = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
        Dim endTime As DateTime = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
        CountedHours = DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, startTime, endTime)

        Return CountedHours
    End If
```

### End Function

Whenever I add the final data to the RadHTMLChart the time returned as the total for all timesheet entries for all users is incorrect. I get a total of "13" hours while the number is 13.5 and for another project I get "17" hours while it should be like 29.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 13 instead of 13.5 because your `DateDiff` is calculating in `DateInterval.Hour`. To get the `decimal` result you are looking for change it to:

```
CountedHours = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, startTime, endTime) / 60
```

As far as getting a result of 17 when 29 is expected...make sure that your inputs are `datetime` and not just `time`, and if the result is the same - post the input values for analysis.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it, do you think that the way im creating the report is correct? im new to charts and pies, generally new to reporting and kinda struggling with it

Comment: @HK Correct is a relative term...I cannot say if it is correct or not. If it were me, I would create a **SQL Stored Procedure** that delivered all of the data you want, already formatted and ready to go, and then just execute the procedure as the `SqlDataSource` for the `RadHtmlChart`. All of the code behind is not required since your Database can do the work for you. See the example at: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/overview/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true and note that there is no code behind. Look at the `<telerik:RadHtmlChart>` and `<asp:SqlDataSource>` sections.